# ASP.NET MVC app take much more RAM on server than on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, server, ram

I've got a problem.

My ASP.NET MVC project takes 9 MB RAM on localhost (tested at ants memory profiler) but at hosting (on server) takes about 400 MB while loading. Then about 150 MB RAM. Why omg? It is single page. [www.algoritmem.cz](http://algoritmem.cz)

I am using entity framework for connecting to MSSQL 2014 database. The database is empty. There arent any data. Just tables.

Comment: I would suggest to you to check few things [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/893660). It might applicable to you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24789260/3514288

Comment: didn't help. btw. i had 'debug=false'

Comment: Why do you think it's using that much memory? Is it an issue?

Comment: I have no idea why it's using that much memory. It's extremely lightweight so i think it's an issue.

Comment: What makes you THINK it is using that much memory?

Comment: I said I have no idea. The page is only showing one single View. In controller is just `return View()`

Comment: Looks like a configuration problem : you could start by checking the application pool parameters. another possible issue is session usage : you could disable SessionState all together (if it's not critical for your app). Another solution would be to deploy your app to a local/LAN instance of IIS, checking if the memory usage is the same, and if you get the same problem, try debugging using IIS (attach debugg to IIS instance or to a remote debugger).